# Эмулятор в Android Studio на Ubuntu выдает ошибку

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

Всем привет, нужна помощь, поставил себе `Ubuntu 14.04` (довольно недавно), решил установить себе `Android Studio`, скачал `Sdk` и `Ide`, написал приложение и решил запустить его на эмуляторе. Он ругается:

> X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no
>   such operation)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  168 ()
>
> Serial number of failed request:  67
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  67

Главное до этого использовал `Ubuntu 14.04` + `Gnome Shell` запускал без проблем.

**Подскажите что делать?**

Comment: возможно, запускаемой программе («эмулятору») недоступен libGL. покажите, пожалуйста, вывод (если будет одна строка) команды `ldd /полный/путь/к/эмулятору | grep -i gl`. если будет больше одной строки, лучше впишите их в вопрос: в комментариях нет разделения на строки.

Comment: А можешь искать где искать полный путь?

Comment: если программа не завершается сразу же, то можно найти её название (а часто и полный путь) в списке процессов. посмотреть их можно командой `ps faux | less` (опция `f` — для представления в виде дерева, что бывает полезно).

Answer (score 1):

Решением данной проблемы стала установка *Genymous*, все работает без проблем